# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\sin\alpha\sin x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\sin \alpha \sin x} dx$$
I need some Hints about how to begin with the problem, because I can't think of anything

Comment: You can get rid of the $x$ in the numerator by doing $x\mapsto \pi-x$ (this symmetry is asked for many times on this site). Then, you will essentially have $\int 1/(1+a\sin x)\,dx$, another integral asked for many times on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

1. Use the fact that $$\int^{\pi}_{0}f(x)dx=\int^{\pi}_{0}f(\pi+0-x)dx$$ where $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\sin \alpha \sin x}$

AND

2. Use the substitution $u=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ after converting $\sin x$ to $\tan \frac{x}{2}$ in the expression $$\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{1+\sin \alpha \sin x} dx$$

Answer (score 3):

Put  $t=\pi-x$ , then you will get

$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{1+\sin\alpha\cdot\sin x} dx=\int_0^\pi \frac{\pi -x}{1+\sin\alpha \cdot \sin(\pi-x)} dx$$

$$\Rightarrow 2I=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\sin\alpha\cdot\sin x} dx$$

Now put  $T=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Note that you can / should use a slash before common functions to get $\sin$ instead of $sin$, and that multiplication can be written using \cdot rather than a period.